# What happens under the hood when call Class.class.getClass()?

Tags: java, class, reflection

It's not hard to understand `String.class.getClass()`, which mean return a <del>Class Object that represent the run time class of String Object</del>. But what's going on when calling `Class.class.getClass()`, can I apprehend it as returning a Class object that represent the run time class of Class object itself? How can this be implemented in Java reflection API?

Comment: `getClass()` is implemented by every Object, its not part of the reflection API (or any other API)

Comment: Oh boy, you are in for a treat if you ever look at Smalltalk's reflection model. Highly recommended.

Comment: you get a constant actually (the code will be compiled to a constant)

Comment: to add to what Peter said, the class is (usually) part of the object header, or in some case it can be part of the reference (pointer) itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a Class object that represent the run time class of Class object itself?

Yes.

But `String.class.getClass()` is the same thing.

`String.class` already means "the object of type Class that represents the String class". Calling `.getClass()` on that means "the object of type Class that represents the Class class", because we're calling it on an object of type Class.

If you have an object that is a String, for example "hi mom", then you can reflect it with `.getClass()`: `("hi mom").getClass()` for example. IIRC, this will return the exact same object as `String.class` in normal circumstances, because there is only one `Class` object per class (, per `ClassLoader` in use).

> How can this be implemented in Java reflection API?

Every time the bytecode for a class is loaded, a Class object is created and associated with that bytecode. Every object conceptually keeps a "hidden" reference to the Class instance that represents its class, that is automatically set by the constructor. Class objects have this reference set to a Class object that represents the Class class. In particular, the Class object that represents the Class class has a reference to **itself**.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> can I apprehend it as returning a Class object that represent the  run time class of Class object itself?
> ```

No. `Object.class.getClass() is same as Class.class.getClass()`.

```
    System.out.println(Object.class.getClass() == Class.class.getClass()); // true
```